# How to write complicated Vertex Buffers

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, vertex-buffer

So I have a particle game, the goal is to have as many as possible. I am working in OpenGL-es 2.0.  Each particle is represented with 2 dots and a rectangle, this results in 6 vertexs' per particle.

I have been running into performance issues using traditional separate buffer methods and so I am now trying some new things such as drawing with arrays.

Here is how I generate my buffers: They are basically

- Square (XyzhsvaXyzhsvaXyzhsvaXyzhsva) (I am hoping I can get indices working)
- Circle (Xyzhsvas) (s is size so I can make it a nice dot)

  ```
  //Array size is preallocated at beginning
  func buildArrays()
  {
     var circlePos:Int = 0
  var rectPos:Int = 0
  var indcPos:Int = 0
  for obj in particles
  {
  let pos:Point = obj.position
  let lpos:Point = obj.lastPosition
  let color:ColorHSV = obj.color
  let width:GLfloat = obj.width
  let rect = Math.makeRectangle(pos, p2: lpos, w: width)

  circles[circlePos] = pos.x
  circles[circlePos + 1] = pos.y
  circles[circlePos + 2] = 0.0
  circles[circlePos + 3] = color.h
  circles[circlePos + 4] = color.s
  circles[circlePos + 5] = color.v
  circles[circlePos + 6] = color.a
  circles[circlePos + 7] = width
  circles[circlePos + 8] = lpos.x
  circles[circlePos + 9] = lpos.y
  circles[circlePos + 10] = 0.0
  circles[circlePos + 11] = color.h
  circles[circlePos + 12] = color.s
  circles[circlePos + 13] = color.v
  circles[circlePos + 14] = color.a
  circles[circlePos + 15] = width
  circlePos += 16


  squares[rectPos] = rect.0.x
  squares[rectPos + 1] = rect.0.y
  squares[rectPos + 2] = 0.0
  squares[rectPos + 3] = color.h
  squares[rectPos + 4] = color.s
  squares[rectPos + 5] = color.v
  squares[rectPos + 6] = color.a
  squares[rectPos + 7] = rect.1.x
  squares[rectPos + 8] = rect.1.y
  squares[rectPos + 9] = 0.0
  squares[rectPos + 10] = color.h
  squares[rectPos + 11] = color.s
  squares[rectPos + 12] = color.v
  squares[rectPos + 13] = color.a
  squares[rectPos + 14] = rect.2.x
  squares[rectPos + 15] = rect.2.y
  squares[rectPos + 16] = 0.0
  squares[rectPos + 17] = color.h
  squares[rectPos + 18] = color.s
  squares[rectPos + 19] = color.v
  squares[rectPos + 20] = color.a
  squares[rectPos + 21] = rect.3.x
  squares[rectPos + 22] = rect.3.y
  squares[rectPos + 23] = 0.0
  squares[rectPos + 24] = color.h
  squares[rectPos + 25] = color.s
  squares[rectPos + 26] = color.v
  squares[rectPos + 27] = color.a
  rectPos += 28

  indices[indcPos] = 3
  indices[indcPos + 1] = 4
  indices[indcPos + 2] = 2
  indices[indcPos + 3] = 3
  indices[indcPos + 4] = 2
  indices[indcPos + 5] = 4
  indcPos += 6
  }
  }
  ```

I have been researching this a lot with things about having elements be in powers of 4, and how to use Indices with triangle strips but still draw separate triangles.

Last time I did buffers I had a separate one for each part however this time I am trying to do better.  I know how to put this data into a buffer object

```
    let sDraw = GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    let sType = GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer_point)
    glBindBuffer(sType, buffer_point)
    glBufferData(sType, circles.count * sizeof(GLfloat), circles, sDraw)
```

However I do not know what to do with this object, how to tell OpenGL what all the separate components work. Nor do I know how to get indices working when the vertex data has color intermingled

I also don't understand the claim someone made that you could get triangle strips to draw separate rectangles somehow with indices.

And I don't understand how OpenGL is supposed to separate each of the pieces of data to get them to my shaders.

Also I don't understand the whole 4 component data thing, or why apple claims I should put random padding before each new vertice (I don't even know how to add two bytes of space)

If anyone could help me with understanding, and solving this that would be appreciated! Any optimization advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you are drawing dots, you could us GL_POINTS for drawing and then set gl_PointSize in your vertex shader. You can do this per vertex. You need to create an interleaved array and use with attributes to tell the shader where to find the vertex and colour data.